# Shortcuts between domains in Typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, realurl

I have a multi-domain Typo3 (4.7.11) Installation with at the Moment four Domains. It is configured with RealURL. The configuration is working so far, but I cannot have shortcuts between domains. The page tree looks like this:

```
domain1
    pageA
    ...
domain2
    shortcut to pageA
...
```

The shortcut is not working, but redirects to the root page of domain2. I believe the problem is not related to RealURL, but I am not sure. I also believe that the multi-domain setup of Typo3 is currect, because all other page types (including a hyperlink page instead of the shortcut). The usual things are included in the TypoScript setup like

```
config {
    baseURL = domain2
    typolinkCheckRootline = 1
    typolinkEnableLinksAcrossDomains = 1

    simulateStaticDocuments = 0
    tx_realurl_enable = 1

    content_from_pid_allowOutsideDomain = 1
    prefixLocalAnchors = all
}
```

Any suggestions? I am even not sure any more whether this should work...

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

Comment: Did you set the "Use as Root Page" flag in the page properties of each root page and the rootpage_id for every domain in realurl configuration?

Comment: Yes, I did (including the root option in the template). The only thing that is a bit strange is the "_DEFAULT" in realurlconf.php, which is the first entry in the array. I read on the dev's blog that this is wrong, but except for the shortcuts, the whole thing works (including typolinks between domains). The problem is that the guy who setup the whole stuff is not available any more...

Comment: One question in between: These shortcuts should, in principle, work? Or am I trying to reach a configuration which is not meant to work?

Comment: Have you created domain in TYPO3 BE like http://screencast.com/t/RkCEWXhFC

Answer (score 1):

First set

> config.tx_realurl_enable = 0

to check, if it is a realurl error or TYPO3 configuration error.

Normally this TS should be enough:

> config.typolinkCheckRootline = 1
>
> config.typolinkEnableLinksAcrossDomains = 1

Now check:

- Is all your typoscript properly loaded in the TSOB (WEB->Template->TypoScript Object Browser)?
- Have you set your "Domain Records" for every Root Site in the Pagetree?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions: I have tested the configuration with RealURL disabled. It behaves exactly the same, i.e. redirects to the root page of domain2, even after clearing all caches. Both, typolinkCheckRootline and typolinkEnableLinksAcrossDomains show up correctly in the object browser. I have domain entries on every root page and they are enabled. I am actually quite clueless...

Comment: AFAIK realurl is a must have for multidomain crosslinking.

Comment: I think it is working without it, too, but the thing is: I do not want to do crosslinking, but cross-domain shortcuts, which might be a different thing.